# Tighter upper bound on $x$ where $2^x \leq \sum_{i=0}^m{{x \choose i}\lambda^i}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We have the following inequality:

$$2^x \leq \sum_{i=0}^m{{x \choose i}\lambda^i}$$

All the variables are in $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$

I need to find a tight upper bound for $x$ using $m,\lambda$.

In the case of $\lambda = 1$ we can use the binomial theorem to show $x \leq m$. However for $\lambda>1$ I have no idea how to find a tight upper bound for this.

It can be shown that:
$$2^x \leq \sum_{i=0}^m{{x \choose i}\lambda^i} \leq \left(\frac{\lambda e x}{m}\right)^m$$

And then we can use the solution from here: [Upper bound $2^x \leq (ax)^c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680582/upper-bound-on-x-where-2x-leq-ax4)

But I need a tighter bound than this. Is there any way to bound $x$ directly from this partial binomial theorem sum?

I thought of maybe doing something like this:

$$2^x = (1 + \lambda)^{x\log_{1 + \lambda}(2)}=(1 + \lambda)^{\frac{x}{\log_2(1 + \lambda)}}=\\ \sum_{i=0}^{{\frac{x}{\log_2(1 + \lambda)}}}{{{\frac{x}{\log_2(1 + \lambda)}} \choose i}\lambda^i} \leq \sum_{i=0}^m{{x \choose i}\lambda^i}$$

But I'm not sure how to continue from here (or if it even helps).

Comment: I suppose that you face an hypergeometric function for the rhs.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not sure what that means, or how can I find an upper bound for x with that.

Comment: You could start with a simple upper bound of $m(x\lambda)^m$ for the RHS.

Comment: @Aravind but I need to find an upper bound for $x$ not for the sum.

Comment: @Aravind what does rhs mean?

Comment: rhs is an abbreviation of 'right hand side' that is often used to denote the expression to the right of an equality-sign, or in this case a 'less than or equal to' sign.

Comment: The contributions of terms with $i > x$ are all zero, right? Or are you using a different convention?

Comment: @Vincent yes it's 0.

Comment: It took me a while to understand why there should be an upper bound on $x$ in the first place but now I do. The right hand side is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $m$. The left hand side grows exponentially in $x$ hand hence for all $x$ above the point where they are equal the inequality is false. So far so good. But then we also see why Aravinds comment is useful: it is relatively easy to compute from which value of $x$ onward the exponential left hand side will be bigger than the degree-m polynomial provided by Aravind and when that happens $2^x$ will also be bigger than the original rhs.

Comment: Are all variables positive?

Comment: @VVejalla yes, all variables are in $\mathbb{N}_{>1}$

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ rather than $\mathbb{N}_{>1}$? You mention in your question that $\lambda$ can be less than $1$.

Comment: @VVejalla Yes, in $\mathbb{N}$ I fixed it now.

Comment: I know you asked for a general bound, but in practice, what are typical values of $m, \lambda$ of interest?  If $m$ is a small integer the rhs is a low-degree polynomial.  OTOH if you are interested in large $m$ then different techniques might apply.

Comment: @antkam $m$ is pretty small and $\lambda$ is large.

Comment: How small is $m$... like $4$?  $10$?  And are $m, \lambda$ related in any way?

Comment: @antkam in my specific case $m$ is either 3 or 4 and $\lambda$ is anywhere between 6 and hundreds of billions. And $m,\lambda$ are not related.

Comment: If $m \in \{3, 4\}$ the right hand side is just a very low degree polynomial...

Comment: @antkam I know, but how do I find a tight bound on $x$?

Comment: @antkam Actually now that I think about it  $m$ can be larger than 4, I'm trying to solve some problem related to k-means with constraints of points that are not allowed to be in the same cluster, and I was trying to bound the VC-dimension of the problem and got the inequality in this question where $\lambda = k!, m= d+1$ so I thought $m$ would probably be 4 (if we're talking about the 3 dimensional space we live in) but I think this problem can also have uses for different values of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment than an answer, but I don't get the same upper bound that you get in the $\lambda \leq 1$ case.

Assuming that $\lambda$ (and hence everything) is positive, it seems to me that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^m{{x \choose i}\lambda^i} \leq \sum_{i=0}^x{{x \choose i}\lambda^i} $$

with equality if and only if $m \geq x$.

But the right hand side of this new inequality equals $(1 + \lambda)^x$, by the binomial theorem.

So substituting this back into the original inequality we obtain:

$$2^x \leq (1 + \lambda)^x$$

When $\lambda > 1$ we get this inequality for free and so we don't learn anything new about $x$, which is similar to the problem you experienced.

When $\lambda = 1$ we have equality in the last inequality I typed, which means that we also need equality in the first equality I typed which impies $x \leq m$ as you also found.

But if $\lambda < 1$ then this inequality puts a rather strong restriction on $x$, namely:

$$x = 0$$

For any $x > 0$ the above inequality with $\lambda < 1$ is violated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In the case it's smaller than 1 then x=0. But I'm more interested in the case it's bigger than 1. In my specific algorithm $\lambda$ is some integer constant that is bigger than 2.