# Upper bound on $x$ where $2^x \leq (ax)^4$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, lambert-w

We have a number $a > 1$ and we know the following inequality:
$$2^x \leq (ax)^4$$

And need to find an upper bound on $x$.

I thought of trying to calculate where $2^x$ intersects $(ax)^4$ and then the larger intersection would be an upper bound for $x$.
So this is what I did:

I called the value where they intersects $t$ and solved:

$$2^t = (at)^4\\
t\ln2 = 4\ln(at)\\
at\ln2=4a\ln(at)\\
\frac{\ln2}{4a}=(at)^{-1}\ln(at)\\
-\frac{\ln2}{4a}=(at)^{-1}\ln((at)^{-1})\\
-\frac{\ln2}{4a}=e^{\ln((at)^{-1})}\ln((at)^{-1})\\
W\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)=\ln((at)^{-1})\\
t=\frac{e^{-W\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)}}{a}$$

And therefore:

$$x\leq \max \left\{\frac{e^{-W_0\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)}}{a},\frac{e^{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)}}{a}\right\}$$

But I don't know how to continue from here. How can I bound this expression with $W$? I need a bound that doesn't use the W Lambert function, instead something like a non-infinite polinomyal or logarithmic function.

Comment: Do you need the exact upper bound or do you just need a valid inequality? If you just need a valid inequality, taking $a=1$ will provide it.

Comment: @PierreCarre why would $a=1$ provide an upper bound? Wouldn't it provide a lower bound? Also I need a relatively tight bound because I use this in some algorithm I'm working on and $x$ is the number of samples I need to do and it would affect the time complexity, it doesn't have to be exactly but the tighter the better.

Comment: You are correct. Why don't you just use Newton's method to get the intersections? You can do it at a very low computational cost. How large can be $a$?

Comment: For $a>1$ 
$\max_{2^t\le(at)^4}(t)=-\frac{4}{\ln2}\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)$.
Algorithm for calculation of $W_{-1}$ is very effective,
so why don't you just use it?

Comment: @g.kov I don't actually care about the time it takes  to calculate it but I want to be able to analyze the time complexity of my algorithm and I need some upper bound for $x$ for that.

Comment: But
$x=-\frac{4}{\ln2}\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln2}{4a}\right)$ is an upper bound,
as good as for example, $x=\exp(a\cdot\mathrm{something})$. 
What do you really need?

Comment: @g.kov something which is intuitively clear and comparable to other algorithms, if I say the time complexity is $O(\log(a)^n)$ everyone understands it and can compare it to other algorithms to see what is faster, but if I write $O(W(...)^n)$ it's kinda hard to compare it to other stuff or have intuition on how fast it is.

Comment: Oh, I see. $W$ is not that common yet. 
I'd suggest to edit the question and add this clarifying info
of what functions you'd like to have in $O(\dots)$.

Comment: @g.kov can you explain how did you got $-\frac{4}{\ln(2)}W_{-1}(-\frac{\ln(2)}{4a})$? I got something else (the value in the question).

Comment: The value is the same, just expressed in a different form: 
$\frac1{a\exp(\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\ln2/(4a)))}=$
$\frac{\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\ln2/(4a))}{a\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\ln2/(4a))\exp(\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\ln2/(4a)))}=$
$-\frac{4}{\ln2}\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\ln2/(4a))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good bounds (have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04895.pdf))
$$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-e^{-(u+1)}) < -1-\sqrt{2u}-\frac{2}{3}u$$ For your case
$$u=-\log \left(\frac{e }{4 a}\log (2)\right)$$